# Proofs with Sets

Tags: real-analysis

Here’s a problem from a prior test. Didn’t do too hot on it so I redid it.  How did I do?

If A and B are any sets, show that A∩B and A\B are disjoint and that 
A=(A∩B)∪(A\B).

My work:

Show that A∩B and A\B are disjoint:
Assume x∈(A∩B)∩(A\B)
then x∈(A∩B)  and x∈(A\B)
⇒x∈A,B and x∈A and x∉B
⇔ 
So ∅=(A∩B)∩(A\B)

Show that A=(A∩B)∪(A\B)
Assume x∈(A∩B)∪(A\B)
then x∈(A∩B) or x∈(A\B)
⇒(x∈A,B) or (x∈A and x∉B)
Either case x∈A

Comment: You have shown that $(A\cap B)\cup(A\setminus B)\subseteq A$.  You still need to the reverse inclusion.

Comment: If x∈A and x∉B then x∉(A∩B) and x∈(A\B).  So x∈(A∩B)∪(A\B).  Then do x is an element of B...

Comment: Yes. That's it. The proof is complete.

Comment: In the first of the two lines that start with "Show ..." I think you need $x\in(A\cap B)\color{blue}{\cap}(A\setminus B)$  not x∈(A∩B)∪(A\B), if you want to show the two are disjoint